# Setting values to loaded xml

Tags: c#, xml

How can I write specific values to my loaded xml? For instance, I want the value of OriginSource to change for PreferenceID 3. What's the most efficient way to do that?

This is a short sample of what I'm trying to do.

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlElement el = (XmlElement)doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("UserObject"));   

                    XmlNode emailAddressXml = UserEmailAddressDTO.AppendChild(doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "EmailAddress", null));
                    emailAddressXml.InnerText = emailaddress;

                    doc.Load("Prefs.xml");

                    XmlNode SourceXml = UserEmailAddressDTO.AppendChild(doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Source", null));
                    originSourceXml.InnerXml = "Good Sam";

    string usrObj = doc.outerXml;
```

Answer (score 2):

Efficiency is subjective so I will provide my recommendation. Depending on .Net version (3.5+ I believe) you should employ [Linq2Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

[`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), [`XElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and [`XAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) are very easy to work with.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("Prefs.xml");

var prefs = doc.Root.Descendents("UserEmailAddressPreferences");
```

Now you can iterate each `XElement` within the `prefs` using Linq. Retrieving and editing values is easy enough:

```
//  untested code
XElement el = prefs.Elements().Where(e => e.Element("PreferenceID").Value == 3)
                              .Select(e => e.Element("OriginSource")
                              .FirstOrDefault();

el.Value = "Something else":
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'merge' but there is no difference between the .Xml file you are loading with DOM (`XmlDocument`) and what `XDocument` loads. Neither object is *interchangeable* - work with one or the other. You have a lot more flexibility with Linq2Xml.

Comment: @TreyCopeland `XmlDocument` is from the `System.Xml` namespace and doesn't offer the LINQ capabilities that `XDocument` offers. However, they both are there to manipulate XML